# How to get Win+R history back on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, run-dialog

Having an upgraded German Windows 10 with latest Fast Ring.

I experience that the "Run" dialog that appears when pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> always has a blank history of previously ran commands.

[image]

This behaviour started right from the beginning, after upgrading Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 and never changed even for the latest Fast Ring update.

**My question:**

Is there any option/trick to make the history of (successfully) ran commands work again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the auto-suggestions and auto complete features were turned off, turn it on through following settings.

There were many ways to achieve it

You could turn on recent searches on:

Right click on the Start button, and click on Properties.

[image]

Ensure **store and display recently opened programs in start menu** it will also enable the start menu and recent command history

Else you could modify it through registry editor:

Open the Start Menu, type `regedit` press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

In `regedit`, navigate to the location below. (see screenshot below)

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoComplete

[image]

Pic credits: Seven forums.

Comment: Thanks. Your registry key did not work (even after reboot) but it led me to the right solution. Will post is right now.

Comment: thanks,hope somehow ur problem got resolved cheers have a good day :)

Answer (score 2):

[BlueBerry's answer](https://superuser.com/a/975835/11720) led me to the right solution:

I had to turn on the "Display recent apps" switch.

[image]

While this also pollutes my start menu again, it indeed gave me back the history on the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> "Run" dialog:

[image]

Comment: As I found this question via google I wanted to leave what I read on another page regarding this issue: `if  the option “Show most used apps” is grayed out (disabled), then do the following. Open the Settings app and go to Settings > Privacy > General. There turn on the switch Let Windows track app launches to improve Start and search results` https://winaero.com/blog/fix-run-does-not-save-command-history-in-windows-10/